# Lost tags in git

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, git-tag

I am facing a problem with git tags when using the maven release-plugin. We have turned off the automatic push to git during `mvn release:perform`, and the following is done to build a new release:

1. Pull the latest changes from remote git repo.
2. `mvn release:prepare`
3. `mvn release:perform`
4. `git push origin master`
5. `git push --tags`

This scenario works, commits are tagged and all is good. But, with this scenario, the tags are lost:

1. Pull the latest changes from remote git repo.
2. `mvn release:prepare`
3. Someone pushes a commit on master!
4. `mvn release:perform`
5. `git push origin master` -- doesn't work, since new commit is in, so
6. `git pull --rebase origin master`
7. `git push origin master`
8. `git push --tags`

Git states that new tags have been pushed, but they are not available for anyone else than me (who made the build), nor are they visible when using `gitk`, so in  all practical uses, the tags are lost.

Is this a bug in git, or is it a usage error (is it our reponsibility to make sure that no commits come in when building)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a usage error. A tag refers to a specific commit, identified by its SHA1 hash. When you type

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

you are rewriting history so that your local changes build on the new state of the remote `master` branch. The commits you tagged are no longer present in this history, although by using `gitk --all` you should be able to see that they are still present in alternative histories in your local repository.

It is probably a mistake to have a `master` branch that is used directly to tag releases as well as being open for pushed commits from multiple developers. You could instead create a new branch for each release, as in [this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this happening once someone has pushed a commit to master during the release phase? Or is sending out emails to everyone warning them not to push anything the only way to do it?

Comment: As per my edited answer, I would suggest not using the master branch for tagging releases, at least if several people can push to it. I don't use Maven so can't really say how you can work around this in your current scheme. Can you delete the tags locally and rerun the Maven commands after your rebasing?

Answer (score 3):

As others already stated, the problem is that tags are not automatically updated to point to the new commit IDs after rebase.

One simple method to avoid this is to just use *merge* instead of *rebase*. Then your commits will not be modified and the tags still point to the right commits.

To your indirect question: The reason why others don't "see" the old tags is because Git by default only fetches tags if they are reachable from a commit that was fetched (e.g. on a branch that was fetched). To get all tags use the following:

```
git fetch --tags
```

This will get the tags, but they will still point to the old (before rebase) commits.

Answer (score 1):

As its being said in the other answer, the rebase is messing up the history so the tags are no longer where they should be.

For now, I was able to get my tag by doing:

remove local git tag:
`git tag -d nameoftag`

remove remote git tag (I had already pushed):`git push origin :refs/tags/nameoftag`

create a new tag, now at the correct place: `git tag nameoftag HEAD` (HEAD could be substituted for sha-id)

and at last, push tags: `git push --tags`

Now other people can enjoy the missing tag, but for the future I think I'll just send out an email that I'm building for release, warning about dire consequences for anyone pushing stuff.